# Heroku pushing from wrong branch

Tags: git, heroku, branch

My workflow with Heroku has usually been the following:

I keep a 'deploy' branch locally - this is where I push from. 
If I need to make a change, I'll branch off of master, (or work in master if it's small), make the change commit to the branch or master, and then checkout deploy. I'll then merge the updated branch into my deploy branch and push from deploy - git push heroku master

Sometime last week, this started breaking down for me. As a test to replicate the issue I did the following

1. In my master branch, I removed the logo for the application
2. I then commited this change to master branch
3. I then checkout deploy
4. I never merge with master
5. git push heroku master
6. Logo disappears on heroku app.
7. master and heroku/master are both at the same commit.

This is driving me nuts. This has been my workflow for over a year now, and I've never encountered this problem. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Step 5: `git push heroku master`

Shouldn't you be doing `git push heroku deploy`. Or **if you want to push from `deploy` in local to `master` in `heroku`, you must do `git push origin HEAD:master`**

Generally, `git push origin master` would push a ref with name master ( mostly `refs/heads/master` ).  If you have to push `deploy` you have to use `git push origin deploy` or `git push origin HEAD`

I think deploy and master were same or similar enough that you did not notice this before.

Comment: git push heroku deploy would create a new branch on heroku named deploy, which heorku would ignore. 'git push heroku master' designates which branch I'm pushing into, not out of.

Comment: @Jarrett If you want to push from deploy in local to master in heroku, you must do `git push origin HEAD:master`. See my updated answer.

Comment: It seems like my answers are being downvoted across questions and without any reason. So bad!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have your development branch or branches locally (this may or may not include master). For deploying w/ heroku, you want to have your deploy branch pushed to the remote master on heroku.

```
git push -u heroku +deploy:master
```

From now, everytime you want to deploy, all you need to do is

```
git push heroku
```

It will only push your deploy branch because that's all you set up to push to the heroku remote.

Hope this helps.